# hard breath supression

Tags: vipassana

I have been practicing vipassana and noticed I was always controling my breath to some degree and this allowed me to achieve near perfectly continuous awareness. The problem is that this isnt right practice because of the suppressesion and it holds back mindlfullness from developing.

I am trying my best to never control my breath at all, short breath then short long then long, hard is hard, etc... however I reached a place where my breath just remains hard is if I am automatically controlling it, when I try to focus on the sensations every in and out breath is so present that it overtakes my awareness and causes me to lose focus. This creates anxiety in the mind because i am unable to focus on the sensations and i am not even doing anything, almost feels like punishment or torture.

I have continue to stay equanimous and remember that sensation or no sensation does not matter, its about accepting the reality as it is. I hope to find some insight sooner or later about this. As of now I feel a bit stuck in anapana, i wonder if someone went throughsomwthing like this? Will my breath settle?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case anyone needs help with this. I have found that going back to step 1 is very helpful. Going back to just breath, nothing else. In and out as it is. Long lobg, hard hard, short dhort, and also easy easy...

I found that as i was expecting, unconsciously i was craving something, and i wasnt aligned with the goal of being with reality as it is...equanimity.. happy practice.

Comment: No self answers buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Remember this golden understanding that

> where ever your attention goes your defilement flows there.

so when you are not focusing on breath its natural. but now its not natural because you are focusing on it. and this goes with any meditation object. It always feels like this meditation object is not good for me. but  believe me its not object its subjective.

but still this understanding is not sufficient to practice mindfulness of breathing. you need some tricks and tips.

1. Try observing breath at different place, necck, chest,belly, palvic and then come back. or keep exploring.
2. Try forcefully breathing  fast, (pranayam). or try forcefully stopping the breathing. for few seconds.
3. observer and stay in gaps between in.out and between out.in. and wait or dont hurry .
4. dont observer breath as object. but inside nose observe sensation at different place. or places near to nose like upper lips. or teeth or facial muscles. or eyes, back of eyes.temporal. etc. this  will reduces the hardness of breathing.
5. hardness of breath can also relate to hardness in muscles of neck, chest, abdomin, palvic region. so better to scan all of then and chekc any hardness.

Comment: I am not sure what you are replying to, or how you received 3 upvotes, rest assured I am not practicing mindfulness of breath, pranayama, and I am not sure what observer of breath as object means. As I wrote I practice vipassana, I appreciate your effort but it was a bizarre read.

Answer (score 0):

Ven Thanissaro's book on breath meditation is excellent - beginner, advanced, comprehensive
https://lucid24.org/tped/s/samadhi/book/than-breath/index.html

Comment: I guess I'll just read a book about it. Thanks for taking the time to advice and think of this detailed response.

Comment: are you being sarcastic? If you read the book, you'll find it answers all of your concerns.  Or would you prefer random internet people give you all kinds of unqualified and dubious advice which will just make you more confused?

Answer (score 0):

**How to be at present?**

Buddha teaches how to be in the present all over the **Damma**. (Buddha's teachings.)
It's about concentration. It's about knowing what's going on in you, around you. (Not dreaming about the past and future.)
You can practice **Samatha meditation** to get absolute concentration.
(This is not the true purpose of Buddha's teaching.)

Now, One should use this concentration/ability to be in the present to understand the **Four Noble Truths**(Nirvana).

Which is **vipassana meditation** (The process of using concentration to understand the Four Noble Truths).

Which is the **main goal of Buddhism**.

Thanks . Any questions are welcome. ☸.